# Erro ao gerar apk signed no android studio

Tags: android-studio, ionic

Ao executar o comando "cordova build --release android", aparece a seguinte mensagem

> Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
>   Looked here: /Users/gustavo/Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper

Já tentei acessar esse path que diz "Looked here" mas a pasta template não existe.

O que devo fazer pra corrigir isso?

Comment: Me parece que o arquivo ficou preso em algum processo. Já resetou a máquina?

Comment: Não! Ajuda? kkkk

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo, não adiantou resetar.